# in core php i need to view an image in a field for editing which is added in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<tr>
   <td class="text-left">Price:</td>
   <td><input type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" value="<?php echo     $result['price'];?>"/></td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td class="text-left">Profile Image:</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="proimage" value="<img src=upload/<?php echo $result['proimage'];?>" height="50px"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my code.but image is not viewing for editing.

Comment: What error do you get in console of your browser? Is it a 404 error for the image?

Comment: you can't embed img tag into file input value attribute

Comment: it shows No file is selected.i want to show that image in a field for editing

Comment: image will not be displayed in input file tag, you have to use img tag for the same

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" name="proimage" value="<img src=upload/<?php echo $result['proimage'];?>" height="50px"/>
                                       ^
                                This is invalid 
                    Like this you can't display image
```

You just need `<img>` tag, to display already available image in db

```
<img src="upload/<?php echo $result['proimage'];?>" height="42" width="42" >
```

And for form you can have, input tag with value,

```
<!-- since already there in db make it hidden -->
<input type="hidden"  name="proimage" value="<?php echo $result['proimage'];?>" />
```

Comment: ya i tried this.but at that time i cant choose another image for updating.

Comment: ok fine.instead of taking image can i take imagename from database.then how i would be re writen this code?